# Conflicts between pytorch and openCV on android

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, arm64

I added

```
implementation("org.opencv:opencv:4.9.0")
```

in my build.gradle.kts file.

I get this error when trying to run my app.

```
2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:
 - C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2616944d5f8a63acb398991752c568fa\transformed\pytorch_android-2.1.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
 - C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d587fbba94c319dd7d2b2c1ae2fc5156\transformed\opencv-4.9.0\jni\arm64-v8a\libc++_shared.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this in build.gradle.kts

```
packaging {
        pickFirst("lib/x86/libc++_shared.so")
        pickFirst("lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so")
        pickFirst("lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so")
        pickFirst("lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so")
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).